# how to make flask route available to svelte and not end user

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-firestore, svelte

I have a flask server that has API like route - `@app.route("/api/v1.0/name/<string:name>", methods=["GET"])`

this go and query a firestore DB i have set up in GCP.
I have set up my frontend to be in svelte. it's still not much, just a field to enter a name, and a button to search for it in my db.

when running my webapp (I first run `python .\server.py` then run `npm run dev` which allows me to see my web page and interact with it. everything works correctly.

my issue is that i don't want users from the internet to be able to send the query directly:
`www.mywebsite.com/api/v1.0/name/alice` which currently is a valid route and i can actually get that way to query my DB directly.

these are the three routes i have in the flask server:

```
def index():
    return send_from_directory("../client/public", "index.html")

@app.route("/<path:path>")
def home(path):
    return send_from_directory("../client/public", path)

@app.route("/api/v1.0/name/<string:name>", methods=["GET"])
def get_by_name(name):
    """
    retrieve by name value
    """
    docs = db.collection(collection_name.where("name", "==", f"{name}").stream()
    return_string = ""
    for doc in docs:
        if doc:
            return_string += f"{doc.info}"

    if not return_string:
        return "No such name"

    return return_string
```

and this is my svelte.app file:

```
<script>
    export let db_result;
    let name_query = "";

    function getNameFromDB() {
        fetch("/api/v1.0/name/" + name_query)
            .then(d => d.text())
            .then(d => (db_result = d));
    }
</script>


<input bind:value={name_query}>
<button on:click={getNameFromDB}>show this name info</button>
{#if db_result}
   <p>"name info: " {db_result}</p>
{/if}
```

I'm not sure where this solution should be, in the flask server? in svelte app? maybe set up a rule in the firestore if that is possible?

Comment: Use some sort of authentication like everyone else...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add authentication to your firestore DB. You can see the docs for this here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#authentication_and_authorization

The relevant is copied below:

> For authentication, the Cloud Firestore REST API accepts either a Firebase Authentication ID token or a Google Identity OAuth 2.0 token. The token you provide affects your request's authorization:
>
> - Use Firebase ID tokens to authenticate requests from your application's users. For these requests, Cloud Firestore uses Cloud Firestore Security Rules to determine if a request is authorized.
> - Use a Google Identity OAuth 2.0 token and a service account to authenticate requests from your application, such as requests for database administration. For these requests, Cloud Firestore uses Cloud Identity and Access Management (IAM) to determine if a request is authorized.

Best of luck!